# Safety of "UV" LED

Tags: led, led-strip, light, uv

I am curious as to whether LEDs like these ones https://www.led4everything.com/index.php/product/waterproof-smd-purple-violet-led-strip-light/ are harmful, they are advertised as UV.

But are they just purple LEDs or actual UV? I see things like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1m0TQjBRcFo and know they are "harmful" but I'm curious if those ones are too. I know that even regular white LEDs can be considered "harmful".

Can UV Leds be harmful to humans?

Comment: This site is not for discussions. Is there a specific question?

Comment: By discussion I mean answers for my question above, sorry for that I don't use this site frequently. Which the question is, are these safe or actual UV? The listing does not mention and I'm just curious about the safety of LED's like this.

Comment: You should look for a datasheet that specifies wavelengths.  I can't find one off-hand when I look at the links you gave.  You might have to email them and ask for a datasheet.

Comment: It's hard to tell as there is no technical data. You could tell by actually looking at the wavelength chart of the LEDs. When you say safety - which aspect you are talking about? The power level of these things is not high enough to harm your skin, but probably not very healthy for your eyes.

Comment: I see, thank you guys for the insight. I'll do some research, thank you again

Comment: First, you find a datasheet on the [UV 5050 LED](http://www.ledlightinghut.com/files/365nm%20UV%20SMD5050%20LED%20datasheet.pdf). Then you ***read*** the datasheet and see what the spectral content is. Then you go and find resources on "damaging UV wavelengths" which will include papers on skin cancer as well as cataracts in the eye and probably still more. Study those, in context. You should find papers showing apoptosis with UVB, but where the apoptosis is halted by the addition of UVA. Etc. Read these papers very carefully. (This isn't a discussion site, by the way.)

Comment: For example, [here's a very short "starter article"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022202X15335545) where you can find that "UVA augments UVB-mediated mutation and skin cancer formation" and which then makes references to other articles. From those, still more. Etc. As you learn, spread out your research still further. Then collate and organize what you've found.

Comment: These are likely "near" UV LEDs.  They do not specify a wavelength.  I would guess they are not below 400 nm.  UV LEDs do not specify a lumen output as these do.  There is no lumen output below 390 nm.  10-12 lumens would be high output for even a deep blue 450 nm LED, so I do not believe these are 10-12 lm .  And no they would not be harmful.

Answer (score 2):

> Can UV LEDs be harmful to humans?

Yes.

You need to look at IEC EN 62471. Photobiological safety of lamps and lamp systems.  https://www.bentham.co.uk/knowledge/insights/articles/photobiological-safety-of-lamps-history-and-overview-of-standards-240/

Answer (score 0):

The strip of LEDs claims to emit "purple color". According to the common color chart,

[image]

the visible "purple color" corresponds to wavelength of about 400 nm.

[CLARIFICATION: In this particular case this seems to be an ordinary 365-nm InGaN LED. A phosphor-based LED would have a deep-UV driver, which are very expensive to make and their luminous efficiency is fairly low, and there is no sense to make them for household illumination purposes. As it is known, most light "conversion" occurs by Stokes shift into lower-frequencies, so for a 365-nm LED there could be no shorter wavelength in the emission spectrum than the main excitation line.]

On the other hand, there is an established model for sensitivity of live tissues to UV emissions, called "[CIE action spectrum](http://www.temis.nl/uvradiation/info/uvindex.html)", which looks as this:

[image]

The interpretation of this chart is that any UV light longer than 320 nm is pretty harmless to living organisms and plants, while lights shorter than 300 nm have 1000X more effect and, with some intensity, would cause harm.

The "germicidal high-pressure Mercury lamps" have strong emission lines at 180 nm and 250 nm, and that's why they are petty harmful to skin and bacteria.

In short, the referenced purple light has 1/10,000 effect as compared to "true UV-B-C lights" that are used to kill bacteria in industrial water purification systems, so the strip is more like a toy. Of course, if you wire a thousand of these strips, there could be some trouble when human skin is in near proximity.

Comment: In general, you can't assume that something that is emitting a visible purple light is not also emitting invisible UV with a lot more energy - the visible portion could be only a weak sidelobe.  It may be possible to deduce things from a sound knowledge of LED technology, but this response seems entirely based on the mention of a visible component in the marketing literature, *which is not a reliable basis* for conclusions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, in general one can't assume anything, this is true. But in this particular case there is an extremely high probability that this is an ordinary 365-nm  InGaN LED, and not some deep-UV LED with  "pink phosphor" on top, which would have no sense to make, especially for household illumination purposes. As you might know, most light "conversion" occurs by Stokes shift into low-frequencies, so there could be no shorter wavelength in the emission spectrum than the main excitation line (unless you have some anti-Stokes upconverting material). Therefore your remark has little grounds.

Comment: While this is true for most damage mechanisms caused by UV light, note that [wavelengths up to 500nm and particularly in the range 400-450nm are considered to be able to cause damage to the eye in sufficient intensity](https://www.aoa.org/Documents/CRG/Blue%20Light%20and%20Eye%20Damage.pdf).  If you're spending a lot of time around bright deep-blue/near-UV light sources, wearing red-tinted glass would be a good idea.  And avoid staring at blue LEDs.

Comment: @Jules, yes, with sufficient intensity anything can happen. I remember a 40-W CO2 laser burning holes in a 3-inch brick...

Comment: @Jules: absolutely correct! "Blue light hazard" is one of the often underestimated risks to the eye. Even cheap 20 mA blue LED can damage the retina like nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the blue and purple can harm your eyes, UVA and UVB can harm eye and skin, and UVC mainly skin and other tissue.

It depends on intensity or radiance and dosage.

Your link did not work for me.

If you need few more details about
UV hazards: [ICNIRP UV guidelines](https://www.icnirp.org/cms/upload/publications/ICNIRPUV2004.pdf)
and [Directive 2006/25/EC](https://osha.europa.eu/en/legislation/directives/directive-2006-25-ec-of-the-european-parliament-and-of-the-council-of-5-april-2006)
LED: [Statements about LED safety](https://www.icnirp.org/cms/upload/publications/ICNIRPled2020.pdf)
:-)